# Jquery UI draggable/resizable containment with multiple divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Fairly new to Jquery, but I have been working with Jquery UI to develop a simulated data center rack with servers modeled from draggable and resizable divs.  I am wondering if there is a good way to prevent these divs from overlapping one another when resizing the div, which you can see happening at my test page http://andrewsit.org/rack.  It would also be useful if these divs could not be dragged to a position that overlapped another div, if that is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go see this :

http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html

And this :

http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/